# Iot.Device.MotorHat and Raspberry Pi4

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, iot, i2c, raspberry-pi4

I have A problem using Iot.Device.MotorHat on Raspberry Pi 4 with Debian-bullseye 11. I am trying run a DcMotor from the raspberry through motor hat pca9685 . My code is:

```
public class DCMotorController : BaseClass
    {
        public void StartMotor()
        {
            using (var motorHat = new MotorHat(1000d, 0x40))
            {
                var dcMotorOne = motorHat.CreateDCMotor(1); // The error is thrown here

                dcMotorOne.Speed = 1;

                Wait(1500);

                dcMotorOne.Speed = 0;
            }
        }
}
```

But on the CreateDCMotor I get an error that I can't figure out

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unexpected value of duty cycle (9766, 10280)
   at Iot.Device.Pwm.Pca9685.<OnOffToDutyCycle>g__OnOffToDutyCycleSampled|16_0(UInt16 onCycles, UInt16 offCycles)
   at Iot.Device.Pwm.Pca9685.OnOffToDutyCycle(UInt16 on, UInt16 off)
   at Iot.Device.Pwm.Pca9685.GetDutyCycle(Int32 channel)
   at Iot.Device.Pwm.Pca9685PwmChannel.get_ActualDutyCycle()
   at Iot.Device.Pwm.Pca9685PwmChannel..ctor(Pca9685 parent, Int32 channel)
   at Iot.Device.Pwm.Pca9685.CreatePwmChannel(Int32 channel)
   at Iot.Device.MotorHat.MotorHat.CreateDCMotor(Int32 motorNumber)
   at projectV2.DCMotorController.StartMotor() in /home/pi/test/DCMotorController.cs:line 13
```

Comment: How long do you need to output a zero?  You may need to add a Wait after setting to zero.  The next event may happen very quickly.

Comment: I don't get there, the error is thrown at ```var dcMotorOne = motorHat.CreateDCMotor(1);```

Comment: Never used IoT, but the docs suggests that `the HAT can be configured in hardware to any address from 0x60 to 0x7f`. Isn't the 0x40 value you provided in the MotorHat constructor out of that range?

Comment: Thanks for the comment I will check the addresses later

Comment: The library is c language not c#.  You need to use Marshal methods to call a c language library from c#.  c# is managed while c language is not managed.  You will get exception if you call c code from c# without using Marshal.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/iot.device.motorhat.motorhat?view=iot-dotnet-2.1 It is definitely for .Net and C#

Comment: The documentation of the Waveshare says that the addresses are from 0x40 to 0x5f. If that is the problem how to solve it !?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the library behaves incorrectly when the current MotorHat configuration is not within the values it would set itself at startup. And the MotorHat binding has no way of correcting this. The following workaround might help (until the behavior is fixed):

```cs
public void StartMotor()
        {
            using (var pca = new Pca9685(new I2cDevice(1, 0xA0), -1, 0, false))
            {
            }
            using (var motorHat = new MotorHat(new I2cConnectionSettings(1, 0x5f), 1000d, MotorPinProvider.Waveshare))
            {
                var dcMotorOne = motorHat.CreateDCMotor(1); // The error is thrown here

                dcMotorOne.Speed = 1;

                Wait(1500);

                dcMotorOne.Speed = 0;
            }
        }
```

The address appears to work, even though the constructor you use uses an offset of 0x60 on the I2C address, so the actual address when specifying 0x40 as argument is 0xA0, which is actually outside the valid ranges for I2C (only 7 bits allowed). I do not know what effect this has. Are there any other devices connected to the I2C bus? Otherwise, a wrong address would give a different error.

I didn't test the above workaround, since I do not have the required hardware.

*Edit:* Updated to reflect the exact constructor call required, after finding that the OP apparently has the "Waveshare" module. And there's quite a bit of confusion on the correct address to use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will check it late and response.

Comment: I change the address of the device to 0x5f physicaly. But now working with 0x40 and 0x5f. I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: I do not know why, but the library expects the address to be 0x60 or larger when using this constructor. Try changing `new MotorHat(1000d, 0x40)` to `new MotorHat(new I2cConnectionSettings(1, 0x5f), 1000d)`, just to make sure the address is used correctly. Do you still get the same error?

Comment: I did it. The address is correct I go through all the code with no errors but it still doesn't fix the motors

Comment: Then you might need to check your wiring (particularly that you use the correct header) and use a multimeter to verify there's voltage on the expected output. If you get no errors but the motor doesn't move, it's probably not a software problem now.

Comment: If I start python script direct from the raspberry with the same address the MotorHat work perfect.

Comment: Can you point me to the python sample you're using?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7euwhFr4

Comment: The python script uses different pins than the default provider you use in your C# script. Change the constructor code again to `new MotorHat(new I2cConnectionSettings(1, 0x5f), 1000d, MotorPinProvider.Waveshare)`. That should give you the same numbering than what the python script uses. Also note that the python script uses a 50Hz PWM signal only, but that's probably less relevant.

Comment: Ok that works now, thank you for your patience and help. Please correct your answer above